# Python NameError only when accessing class attribute in class namespace within list comprehension

Tags: python

For the following code:

```py
class Test:
    BAR = 'world'
    FOO1 = "%s" % BAR
    FOO2 = ["%s" % BAR for _ in range(1)]
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<redacted>", line 1, in <module>
    class Test:
  File "<redacted>", line 4, in Test
    FOO2 = ["%s" % BAR for _ in range(1)]
  File "<redacted>", line 4, in <listcomp>
    FOO2 = ["%s" % BAR for _ in range(1)]
NameError: name 'BAR' is not defined
```

Notice from the traceback that the error only occurs when accessing `BAR` from within a list comprehension - this is very puzzling as I would assume a list comprehension would share the scope it was called from, so I have two questions:

- why is this happening?
- is there any way to accomplish this? ie using a class attribute in a list comprehension to declare another class attribute?

This is on CPython 3.9

Comment: basically the short solution is this: `FOO2 = (lambda bar=BAR: ["%s" % bar for _ in range(1)])()`